# Why am i getting 403 error reading a website url on java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to read http://www.meuhumor.com.br/ on java using this:

```
URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;        
        try{
            url = new URL(targetURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); 
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream dataout = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dataout.flush();
            dataout.close();

            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
            String html = response.toString();
```

I can access the website using any browser, but when i try to get the html with Java im getting java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:

Someone know a way to get the html?

Comment: Why do you POST to the server?

Comment: I tried with GET before and got the same error... I read somewhere saying me to use this code with post so it worked to another website, but not for this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely getting an HTTP 403 response because your `POST` request has no body. Your code looks like it's trying to submit a form. If your intention was to simply pull down the page content without submitting a form, try a `GET` request, remove the `Content-Type` header,  remove `connection.setDoOutput(true)`, and remove the 3 `DataOutputStream` lines.

Comment: So, what should i do? i use that same code in another website and i can read the html...